# Primefaces Wizard doesn't execute onclick method call

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wizard

I try to build a form where a user can enter data step by step. After trying a FlowScoped solution I now try to implement the Primefaces wizard.

**Description:**

My main.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="antragErfassenForm">
    <p:wizard showStepStatus="false" widgetVar="wiz" showNavBar="false" >
        <p:tab id="basic_decision_tab" title="Grundsatzentscheidungen">
            <ui:include src="/eAkte/basic_decisions.xhtml" />
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="driving_ways_tab" title="Fahrtwegvarianten">
            <ui:include src="/eAkte/driving_ways.xhtml" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:wizard>
</h:form>
```

Inside the include files I have buttons to navigate between the tabs.
The next button in the first tab 'basic_decisions.xhtml':

```
<p:commandLink value="Next" onclick="#{eAkteController.callDrivingWays()}; PF('wiz').next();" />
```

Depending on the result from callDrivingWays() (which evaluates the data of the first tab) the second tab has a different content.

**My problem:**

The method callDrivingWays() isn't called when clicking the next button on the first tab. Instead it is already called when the first tab is loaded. That's why I always have an empty second page.

I tried switching the method call callDrivingWays() inside an actionListener inside the button or the flowListener of the Wizard. After that the method is called at the correct time, but when clicking on the next button I get an exception, that my component ID has already been used before.

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: the onclick attribute is for executing javascript, not server side methods. Most likely you have an error in your browser developer tool

Comment: So I have to put the method back in the actionListener and fix the exception of double component ids?

Comment: yes, indeed.... AND ask a new question (this one is in fact a duplicate of some existing ones. No time to find out however

Answer (score 0):

Try using the flowListener attribute of p:wizard

```
<p:wizard flowListener="#{yourBB.yourMethod}" nextLabel="Next" backLabel="Back" showNavBar="false" widgetVar="myWizard">
```

In your backing bean code instead you can implement the actionListener like this:

```
public String yourMethod(FlowEvent event) {
    if(event.getOldStep().equals("driving_ways_tab")){}
    if(event.getNewStep().equals("driving_ways_tab")){}
```

you need getOldStep and getNewStep to perform some changes according to the tab you are entering, exiting.